# nodeJs .save() did not save data in my database

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql

everyone...when I tried to use function .save(), it's did not work but there is no error

that's mutation for signup and it's when i call etudiant.save() which does not work even if i use await or not

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const { GraphQLList, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLID, GraphQLNonNull } = graphql;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Etudiant = mongoose.model("etudiant");
const AuthService = require("../../services/auth");
const EtudiantType = require("./etudiant_type");
const { GraphQLUpload } = require("graphql-upload");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const _ = require("lodash")
    signup: {
          type: EtudiantType,
          args: {
            nom: { type: GraphQLString },
            prenom: { type: GraphQLString },
            classe: { type: GraphQLString },
            etablissement: { type: GraphQLString },
            email: { type: GraphQLString },
            password: { type: GraphQLString },
            telephone: { type: GraphQLString }
          },
          async resolve( parentValue, { email, password, nom, prenom, classe, etablissement, telephone }, req ) {
            const etudiant = new Etudiant({email, password, nom, prenom, classe, etablissement, telephone});
    
            etudiant.password = await bcrypt.hash(etudiant.password, 12);
    
            etudiant.save();
    
            return etudiant;
          }
        },
```

Comment: can you share the complete file?

Comment: i have add the code on complete file, the rest is just another function

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `await` with `.save()` as it returns a promise

```
await etudiant.save()
```

Comment: "Does not work" doesn't help us. Have you enabled database logging? Does it show any query activity? Do you get any errors?

Comment: that's the big problem there is no error, and when i check my database there's nothing inside

the return work fine(if i don't use await) but the .save() does not work. And if i use await that's load and while and stop after a several second